# jdbcTemplate batchUpdate is throwing ClassCastException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I want to insert multiple records to mysql database using jdbcTemplate, so I choose to use the batchUpdate method, this is my code:

```
        @Override
public void actualizarAmortizaciones(List<Amortizacion> lstAmortizaciones) {
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("{call contable.spact_amortizaciones(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}", new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
            Amortizacion objAmortizacion = lstAmortizaciones.get(i);
            ps.setString(1, objAmortizacion.getStrId());
            ps.setString(2, objAmortizacion.getStrTarjeta());
            ps.setInt(3, objAmortizacion.getIntNumeroAmortizacion());
            ps.setDate(4, (Date) objAmortizacion.getDatFechaPago());
            ps.setString(5, objAmortizacion.getStrHoraPago());
            ps.setInt(6, objAmortizacion.getIntCubierto());
            ps.setBigDecimal(7, objAmortizacion.getBdTotalPagado());
            ps.setBigDecimal(8, objAmortizacion.getBdCapitalPagado());
            ps.setBigDecimal(9, objAmortizacion.getBdInteresPagado());
            ps.setBigDecimal(10, objAmortizacion.getBdIvaPagado());
        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
            return lstAmortizaciones.size();
        }
    });
}
```

The next line is throwing an error

```
Amortizacion objAmortizacion = lstAmortizaciones.get(i);
```

this is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.bo.Amortizacion
    at com.dao.impl.TransaccionDAO$1.setValues(TransaccionDAO.java:49)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:956)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:946)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:946)
    at com.dao.impl.TransaccionDAO.insertarAmortizaciones(TransaccionDAO.java:44)
```

Have someone know why this is happening?,

Thanks in advance.

**Updated**

I get the list parsing from json(I'm using gson) with the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RabbitListener(queues = "generarAmortizacionesContable")
public void generarAmortizaciones(String json){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Amortizacion> lstAmortizaciones = gson.fromJson(json, List.class);
    transaccionBS.insertarAmortizaciones(lstAmortizaciones);
}
```

But I noticed that when I debug my code the list contains LinkedTreeMapElements so I don't know if this is a good behavior

Comment: What is the type of `lstAmortizaciones` and where are you getting that list from?

Comment: Let me update my question to explain myself better, know you can see my change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I noticed that my problem was the format of the json input and the parsing of that json, so when I convert the list to json I use the following code:

```
List<Amortizacion> lstAmortizaciones = amortizacionDAO.generarAmortizaciones(objTransaccion);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL).create();
String json = gson.toJson(lstAmortizaciones);
```

And when I need to convert the json to the list I use this code:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Amortizacion>>() {}.getType();
List<Amortizacion> lstAmortizaciones =  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat(DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL).create().fromJson(json, listType);
```

So the problem was that the parsing was converting the list to a LinkedTreeMap list so when I decide to use the TypeToken class it throws an error about the date format because the convertion of the list to the json was leaving the date like 25 august,2016 so the gson not know how to convert that list, then I specify the date format using the gsonBuilder and works perfectly, hope this helps someone.